# Structuring application to comply with Single responsibility

Tags: java, solid, single-responsibility

I have the class `AircraftManager` that keeps track of a list of `Aircraft` objects and a list of `AircraftListener` objects.

A `DataSource` (custom class, not sql related) object retrieves information from an external source, the data sources decodes the message and calls appropriate logic on the aircraft, i.e setAltitude, setHeading. The program is designed to plot Aircraft onto a live map.

calling the setters on Aircraft should trigger the `onAircraftUpdate(Aircraft aircraft, String fieldName, Object fieldValue)` method on each registered `AircraftListener` in the AircraftManager

This first of all requires the `Aircraft` to keep a reference of the `AircraftManager` to invoke methods on the event listeners as such:

```java
public void setAltitude(int altitude) {
    if (this.altitude != altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.aircraftManager.getListeners().forEach((aircraftListener ->
                aircraftListener.onAircraftValueChanged(this, "altitude", longitude)));
    }
}
```

This also means AircraftManager has a responsibility to keep hold of all AircraftListeners as well as Aircraft.

My question is whether this solution is satisfactory, any improvements/changes you would make. It's also worth noting that a class will not want to add a listener upon a single aircraft, but all aircraft.

Comment: Recommended Reading:  https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html  -- also, another thing you could consider when it comes to passing events between objects might be to use a *Mediator*, such as the one in this LIbrary:  https://github.com/sizovs/PipelinR

Comment: Who is deciding to change the altitude, and why?

Comment: What, at a high level, does the application do?

Comment: @GregBurghardt A `DataSource` (custom class, not sql related) object retrieves information from an external source, the data sources decodes the message and calls appropriate logic on the aircraft, i.e setAltitude, setHeading. The program is designed to plot Aircraft onto a live map.

Comment: This is crucial information to add to you question text. Can you edit your question and add this info? It gets lost in comments too easily.

Comment: And why do the aircraft need to broadcast their altitudes? What cares how far off the ground each plane is flying?

Comment: Ground control?  Assuming something like that exists in this scenario.  If something is coordinating the flight paths of multiple aircraft, then altitude is vitally important.

Comment: Related to the code, but not necessarily the question: You are publishing the longitude as if it were the altitude in your example.  I assume this is a typo or artifact of copy/pasting the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The example code you provided feels like a variant of something known as an `EventBus` where consumers can register for the type of event they care about.  The single responsibility for the EventBus is to deliver events of a specific type to all the listeners registering for that event.

The listening code would register for the type (or base type) of event it wants to receive.  In pseudo code it would look like this:

```
eventBus.register<AirplaneEvent>(event -> onAircraftChanged(event));
```

In your producer side of the equation you would publish the specific event:

```
public void setAltitude(int altitude) {
    if (this.altitude != altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.eventBus.publish(new AltitudeChangedEvent(this, altitude));
    }
}
```

Another solution would simply be a publish/subscribe message bus.

In each of these concepts the idea of publish and subscribe are integral parts of the responsibility of delivering events to the listeners.  Now, what you don't see in this example is the `forEach()` call you did in the listener.  That's the responsibility of the EventBus or Message Bus.  Inside the EventBus would be the filtering logic to deliver only the events/messages that a listener had registered for.  None of the listeners are exposed to the class calling `publish()`

If you needed to handle dead-letter queuing or managing unhandled events in some way, that is solely the responsibility of the `EventBus` or message queue.  None of the code from the subscriber or publisher role must change.